# What does ".initialize" do in ActionScript 2.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

What does `.initialize` do in ActionScript 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the index of ActionScript 2, there's only one reference to an `.initialize()` method, which belongs to the [`AsBroadcaster`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000756.html) class:

[image]

As for what it does, seems to just add some functionalities to any Object instance.

> `initialize(obj: Object) : Void`
>     Adds event notification and listener management functionality to a given object.

Comment: So in simple language, it registers that object to compiler, as an Event target which means there is at least one event which will works with this object. Is that true?

Comment: @KataxEmperorKatax Seems that way.